# Setting custom date and time for UIDatePicker in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have to set custom date and time to UIDatePicker as
Minimum Date: current date time,
Maximum Date: till tomorrow night.

**Eg:
Today is 2nd March then, Maximum Date should be 3rd March 11:59 PM**

i tried:

```
-(NSDate *) getTomorrowDate {

    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = 1;
    dayComponent.hour = 23;
    dayComponent.minute = 59;
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date:[NSDate date] withFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"] options:0];

    return nextDate;
}
```

but its returning 4th March also, kindly correct me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution which adds two days, strips the time portion and subtracts one second.

```
- (NSDate *)getTomorrowDate {
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  // add two days
  NSDate *dayAfterTomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:2 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
  // get start of the day
  NSDate *startOfDayAfterTomorrow = [calendar startOfDayForDate:dayAfterTomorrow];
  // subtract one second.
  return [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitSecond value:-1 toDate:startOfDayAfterTomorrow options:0];
}
```